# Are these Ports safe to have open?

Tags: ports

I have a netgear router I recently hooked up to my other router provided by Xfinity(It sucks ass*). And I mostly use this router for my PS4 and Raspberry Pi because it just has a better wifi signal than the Xfinity.
But I currently did a NMAP scan of my router and came up with this:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.0018s latency).
Not shown: 991 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
53/tcp    open  domain
80/tcp    open  http
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
548/tcp   open  afp
631/tcp   open  ipp
5000/tcp  open  upnp
8200/tcp  open  trivnet1
20005/tcp open  btx
MAC Address: E4:F4:C6:xx:xx:xx (Netgear)
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 2.6.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6
OS details: Linux 2.6.19 - 2.6.36
```

I have currently updated the routers firmware since the recent botnet attacks and the exploit of the NETGEAR routers which is suppose to cure my R7000.

Im curious if these ports alert anybody?

Comment: From where did you port scan? Inside the network, or from the internet?

Comment: That scan is from inside your network, which isn't going to tell you much...

Comment: And which router is reporting that, the Xfinity (presumably that's your Internet router?) or the Netgear?

Answer (score 4):

You are performing an NMAP scan from inside the network. Just because these ports show as being open internally, doesn't mean they show as being open outside of the network.

Grab your external IP and run an online port scan - this will give you an idea of what ports are open to the world, or a potential 'hacker'.

Comment: This is a scan from the internal network. It is a netgear.  n3tw0rkslayer: I'll be back with the results with the outside network scan on to my Xfinity router.   Tchotchke: yes that is my setup.

Answer (score 1):

We need a little more information.

Is your current setup:

```
Xfinity <---> Netgear <---> Internal Network
```

If it's this then it's less important what's open on the Netgear and what's actually allowed through on the Xfinity router.  Use an online port scanner and it'll tell you what your outermost router is allowing through.  That's the list you should be concerned with.

Comment: This is a scan from the internal network. It is a netgear.  n3tw0rkslayer: I'll be back with the results with the outside network scan on to my Xfinity router.   Tchotchke: yes that is my setup.